# In JMockIt, what is a @Mock final parameter

Tags: jmockit

I'm completely new to JMockIt. In the tutorial I see example codes that uses the **final** modifier for a @Mocked parameter e.g.

```
  @Test
   public void doSomethingHandlesSomeCheckedException(@Mocked final DependencyAbc abc) throws Exception
   {
    ...
   }
```

What does **final** mocked parameter mean here? Sometimes, "final" is not used. What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is merely a Java language issue, nothing to do with JMockit itself. For a method parameter or local variable to be used inside an inner class (anonymous or not), the Java compiler requires it to be declared as `final`.

Answer (score 0):

From the JMockit tutorial:

"For a mock parameter declared in a test method, an instance of the declared type will be automatically created by JMockit and passed by the JUnit/TestNG test runner when calling the test method. Therefore, the parameter value will never be null.

For a mock field, an instance of the declared type will be automatically created by JMockit and assigned to the field, unless it's a final field. In such case, a value should be created and assigned to the field explicitly in test code. This value can be null, though, which is perfectly valid for a mocked class if only constructors and static methods are going to be called on it."

http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/tutorial/BehaviorBasedTesting.html#declaration

Keep in mind that a mock parameter/field is any annotated with @Mocked or @Injectable.

Comment: But why the *parameter* (mock parameter != mock field) has to be declared "final"? The tutorial only talk about final mock field, but I can't find any description related to final parameter.